# Uninstall and re-install pip package from python module

Tags: python, pip

I have uninstalled package 'setuptools' from python using following pip function

```
import pip
pip.main(['uninstall','--yes','setuptools'])
```

When, I tried to re-install the same package again using below command, it throws the following error message

```
pip.main(['install','setuptools'])
```

Error:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages
```

Is there any option to overcome this ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `--ignore-installed`. For more info: `pip install --help` which explains:

```
-U, --upgrade               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest
                            available version. This process is recursive
                            regardless of whether a dependency is already
                            satisfied.
--force-reinstall           When upgrading, reinstall all packages even if
                            they are already up-to-date.
-I, --ignore-installed      Ignore the installed packages (reinstalling
                            instead).
```

Besides, I tried it with Python 3.4. Of the above options, only `pip install --ignore-installed` would install a previously installed package.

Comment: I had partly uninstalled pip it seems, since pip wasnt reckogized as a command and i couldn't run python -m pip "whatever". Executing python get-pip.py wouldnt solve anything. But **python get-pip.py --force-reinstall did**. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall won't take effect until next time python is started.
So to uninstall and reinstal what you could do is divide your code into 2 files.

File "main.py":

```
import pip
import os

pip.main(['uninstall','--yes','setuptools'])
os.system('python install_setuptools.py')
```

File "install_setuptools.py":

```
import pip

pip.main(['install','setuptools'])
```

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't take affect until next python restart.  But why?  And is it possible to workaround it in the same interpreter??